# Given marked cells in a 2D Array, find duplicate shapes formed by those marked cells

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, multidimensional-array, shapes

Given a 2D array with cells which are marked and combined together forms different linear shapes, how would you identify duplicate shapes.

0010000100000000000000000000
0010000100000000000000000000
0011100100000100000000011100
0000000100000111111000000000
0010000111100100000000000000
0110000000000001111000000000
0010000100000000000000000111
0000000001000000000011110000
0000000001111110000000000000
0010000001000000000000000000

Here we have 3 duplicate shapes :
1
111111
1

111

1

What i have thought so far is:
To store shapes i will make tree for each shape, the node structure will be

```
    typedef struct node{  
        struct node * leftchild;  
        struct node * rightchild;  
        struct node * downchild;  
    };
```

1. I will traverse the matrix cell by cell also maintaining a visited[][] array.
2. When i find a '1' which is unvisited, i will make a new node for that cell and mark that node as a root node for that shape as this would be the first node to be visited for that shape.
3. then i will check immediate left, right and down cells of the root cell found in step 2 and (if 1)add them to corresponding roots' child nodes. And repeat it with these left right and down cell to complete tree for that shape.

In step 2, i will also store the root elements in an array.

Now i have root elements for every shape. I will have to compare each and every tree represented by the root nodes present in the array to find out any duplicate shapes.

will this solution work? Moreover i feel complexity will be huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that will work. The question is now to compare the trees you obtain.

For example, you can denote any left-traverse of the tree by a string of letters `L,D,R,B` (B for back). Trees in your example will have `'DDBRRRRRBBBBBB'`, `'RRBB'` and `''` (empty) encodings. Obviously same trees have same encodings and vice versa.

Now for each tree we've got some string representation. We can go further, and calculate hashes of that strings. Lets say we've got that H array of hashes. Now to find the duplicates we can sort the array of hash values, and all the same hashes will group together.

To restore which of the original shapes (trees) are the same, just need to keep the reference to the tree along with hash, so that order shuffle after sorting doesn't make a problem.

**Complexity**. Let's say grid size is `NxM` and it contains `K` shapes. The tree construction part is `O(N*M)` (hashing also here, you can calculate hashes on-the-fly), and the sorting `O(K*logK)`. Assuming `K=O(N*M)` will lead to `O(N*M)+O(N*M*log(N*M)) = O(N*M*log(N*M))` complexity. Not huge at all)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add this: for each recognized shape, store the number of 1's. Then you only have to call on a (probably costly) full comparison routine when two shapes have the same number of 1's.
Additionally, a second cheap check would be the number of rows and columns in each shape.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler linear shape can be represented by a number e.g.

```
1
111111 
1
```

can be represented as 111.161 based on index of left most one and right most one. Left most indexs are on left side of decimal and right indexes are on right side of decimal.

Right move and down are valid moves to construct one connected component. Other moves generate a list. Another example

```
  1111
1111111
 111
```

can be broken down as

```
    1111
11  11111
 1  11
```

this can be represented as 111.452->12.11

Similarly example with gaps

```
111 111
  1111
```

can be broken down as

```
111     111
  1111
```

this can be represented as 13.36->1.3

Since digits represent width of 1s in a pattern, we can only process rectangles of width at max 9 in one shot.

```
111111111111
```

can be represented as

```
111111111 111
```

1.9->1.3

Hence every pattern is represented as list of floats. Since you are scanning the every element only once it should take O(N) time. To find duplicates you can just sort the elements.

Assuming there are n connected components, where each component is represented as list of length at max m. So overall O(nlogn*m).

Comment: i think i got what u said but what we will do for this input: 
  11  11 
 1111111
  111.
 Hey i am unable to display the input. But say first row has 1s from index 2-3 and then from 5-6. These 1s at index 5-6 are connected with 2nd row. how do we store them then